# Defining the result of an SQL query as a variable - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am VERY VERY new to Python.

I have all of my connections set up and am able to run SQL queries that write tables to my Oracle SQL environment.

What I am trying to do:
I want to be able to run a SQL query and have the output of the results be set as a defined variable in Python.

For example:
Select Distinct Longitude, Latitude From Address_Table where Store = 1234

I would like the output of that query to be a variable that I can then use in Python
Something like:

```
address_long_lat = SQL_Execute("Select Distinct Longitude, Latitude From Address_Table where Store = 1234")
```

I'm aware that this is probably not a great way to ask or phrase this question, so be patient with me!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Use the `cursor.fetchall()` method to retrieve the results of a query into a variable.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on making SQL queries in Python. They should all have examples of this.

Comment: Which library is this? Google doesn't turn up any that use `SQL_Execute`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do `cursor.fetchall()` to get everything in a single variable :)